# Text is not printed when using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

This is the code I have written so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

chrome_driver_path = "C:\Development\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.ae/Kingston-SA400S37-480G-480GB-A400/dp/B01N6JQS8C/ref=lp_12050241031_1_12?th=1")
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[7]/div[3]/div[4]/div[11]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span[1]/span[1]').text
print(price)



#driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

This doesn't print out the price, please help.
This is what the output terminal looks like.
[image: output terminal]

I want to get this price:
[image: price]

Comment: Then the `text` attribute must be blank.

Comment: I still didn't get it, what do you mean?

Comment: You didn't say that the program throws an exception, so the `print()` must be executing.  If you don't see any output, it must mean that `find_element_by_xpath()` found an element with blank text.  So your xpath might be wrong.

Comment: When you find that element manually, what is the text on it? You may be looking for the value attribute or something similar instead.

Comment: Pls see the edit, and the xpath points to it, I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the **price** is blank.

You should replace the tailing `span[1]` with `span[2]` in your `xpath`

Here is the code -

```
from selenium import webdriver


chrome_driver_path = "drivers\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.ae/Kingston-SA400S37-480G-480GB-A400/dp/B01N6JQS8C/ref=lp_12050241031_1_12?th=1")
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[7]/div[3]/div[4]/div[11]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span[1]/span[2]').text
print("price: ", price)

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Output -

```
price:  AED81.64
```